# Jetbrains "Warning: not all local changes" may be shown due to an error: svn: E204899: Cannot read from {path_to_temp_files}

Tags: svn, ubuntu, permissions, jetbrains-ide

Getting error
**Jetbrains "Warning: not all local changes" may be shown due to an error: svn: E204899: Cannot read from {path_to_temp_files}**
when trying commit my files, how can I add Jetbrains SVN user to www-data apache group in ubuntu.

Answer (score 34):

In my situation, the error was showing E720005 for a strange file. I tried svn clean, then in IDE **File > Invalidates and Restart** and the error was gone.

Comment: I have the same issue with PyCharm on Windows, your advice helped me.

Comment: IntelliJ 2016 on Windows too after quite a few huge refactorings. Invalidating cache and restarting worked, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I receive the same warning message using IntelliJ Idea 14.0.3 on Windows 8, and Subversion. This is happening quite often now.

It only gets fixed **for a while** if I close the IDE and start it again. Perhaps closing all projects before closing the IDE is a complementary step.

[image: Warning message]

Comment: No. This happens almost in a random way, specially in very big repositories. This has never happened to me with Git. This is not a very serious problem, in fact I fix it by simply saving files and restarting the IDE. After that SVN detects all changes without problems.

Comment: Thanks David,
Actually I found a way to solve the issue on windows ( never had issues on linux ).

The way i proceeded was the following :
- In the subversion settings ( File > Settings > Version Control > Subversion ), uncheck the "use command line client".
- click ok, close the window, restart intelliJ
- check "use command line client" again, restart
- should be ok

Answer (score 1):

1) - **sudo xcodebuild -license** ( write 'agree' after then enter q  )

2) - **File > Invalidate Caches & Restart >Invalidate and Restart**

Take it be easy

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data userName
```

taken from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/add-user-to-existing-group)

But your problem might be a different one... jetbrains cannot call svn in the mentioned directory. Try to manually call it there and check what svn says.